# Woocommerce - Print Product's Custom Field In Email

Tags: customization, plugins

In Woocommerce 2.0, I need to print a custom field on the New Order email.

It is a meta/custom field each product has named "longsku" (which is normally hidden.)

This needs to be included in the email-order-items.php email template but I am not certain what syntax is necessary to print it.

For instance, variations are printed like so within the email template:

```
echo ($item_meta->meta) ? '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true ) ) . '</small>' : '';
```

Does anyone have experience printing custom fields from products (not from actual checkout) in the email templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the longsku is regular wordpress post meta, so you can simply call that with  [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

get_post_meta takes three arguments:

- post_id (which is already available in $_product)]
- meta key ('longsku' in your case)
- and a boolean to return a single string (true). if not set, it returns an array, but since the meta key is just a single value you can use true

this should do the trick for your longsku:

```
echo get_post_meta($_product->id,'longsku',true);
```